# Color is not responsive when Drawig a Circle function inside a loop

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I would like to draw circles in a loop. I want each circle to have a different color, but when I do this, I only get one color.

I tried the code on [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hjYB_KZ4CzaupE9pSaZ6yLVxiIClLjeN?usp=sharing) 4.1.2

```
from numpy import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

mat = np.zeros((500,500,3))
def color():
   return (  random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255))

for _ in range(10):
   x_coord = random.choice(500)
   y_coord =  random.choice(500)
   color_person = color()
   cv2.circle(mat, (x_coord, y_coord), 10, color=color_person,thickness=20)
   
plt.imshow(mat)
```

[image: cv2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `mat` as `uint8` type:

```
mat = np.zeros((500,500,3)), np.uint8)
```

---

`matplotlib` conversion is:

- NumPy arrays of type `float` applies pixel range [0, 1].
- NumPy arrays of type `uint8` applies pixel range [0, 255].

You are using `plt.imshow(mat)`, when type of `mat` is `float`.
All values above or equal `1.0`, are at maximum intensity (equivalent to `255` in `uint8`).
RGB triplet at maximum intensity applies white color.

---

Complete code:

```
from numpy import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

mat = np.zeros((500, 500, 3), np.uint8)  # Create mat with type uint8 

def color():
   return (random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255))

for _ in range(10):
   x_coord = random.choice(500)
   y_coord = random.choice(500)
   color_person = color()
   cv2.circle(mat, (x_coord, y_coord), 10, color=color_person, thickness=20)
   
plt.imshow(mat)
plt.show()
```